# Which estimator is better?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, parameter-estimation

$X=\left(X_{1},...,X_{n}\right), Y=\left(Y_{1},...,Y_{n}\right)$ - independent sample from distributions $\mathcal{N}\left(m_{x},\sigma^{2}\right)$ and $\mathcal{N}\left(m_{y},\sigma^{2}\right)$. Which of these two estimators of $m_xm_y$:
$$T_{1}\left(X,Y\right) = \overline{X}\overline{Y}\\
T_{2}\left(X,Y\right) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}Y_{i}$$
is better when we apply quadratic loss function? Can I ask for a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both estimators are unbiased thus, according to the Classical Statistical Theory,  you can evaluate them comparing their variance.

After some calculations I get

$$\mathbb{V}[T_1]=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\left[\frac{\sigma^2}{n}+m_X^2+m_Y^2\right]$$

$$\mathbb{V}[T_2]=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}[\sigma^2+m_X^2+m_Y^2]$$

thus I prefer $T_1$ as its variance is always lower that the one of $T_2$ for any $n>1$

---

To compare two estimators in Classical Statistical Theory, the one having the lower MSE is preferred.

By definition,

$$MSE_{T_1}=\mathbb{E}[T_1-\mathbb{E}[T_1]]^2$$

In your statement you assumed immediately that $\mathbb{E}[T_1]=\mathbb{E}[T_2]=m_X\cdot m_Y$

... which is correct but it has to be verified first...

---

$$\mathbb{V}[T_1]=\mathbb{V}[\overline{X}\overline{Y}]=\mathbb{E}\left[(\overline{X})^2\right]\cdot \mathbb{E}\left[(\overline{Y})^2\right]-m_X^2\cdot m_Y^2$$

now observe that $\overline{X}\sim N(m_X ;\sigma^2/n)$

thus

$$\mathbb{V}[T_1]=\left(\frac{\sigma^2}{n}+m_X^2\right)\left(\frac{\sigma^2}{n}+m_Y^2\right)-m_X^2\cdot m_Y^2$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately during the statistics course, I did not have this statement yet and I have to solve this problem in some other way, probably by calculation the expected losses using both estimators. I edit my question a little bit, can you look at this and maybe give me a hint how to show this inequality?

Comment: @Kerni what you stated is exactly what I did...to calculate the 2 variances. Before doing that you have to verify that the 2 estimators are unbiased..do you need further help?

Comment: How did you calculate $\mathbb{V}[T_1]=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\left[\frac{\sigma^2}{n}+m_X^2+m_Y^2\right]$ I try to calculate it above, I must forget about sth

Comment: @Kerni : added some details...I think it is better to write your attempts directly in you answer

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @tommik Your first conclusion is right. Both of us made error on $V(T_2)$

Comment: @NN2: actually I trusted in your result without checking it...now I checked it but I am working, thus did calculations very quickly...can you check them? it is the matter of expanding the matrix...

Comment: I added my calculation to my question. I get the same result as you posted at the beginning. Is there any mistake?

Comment: @NN2: checked again and I confirm my first answer

Comment: @tommik Yes, your answer is correct. I missed the term $-E^2(XY) = -m_x^2m_y^2$ in my calculation